# inline SVG make parent DIV height bigger than the actual SVG height and also shift it up

Tags: html, svg, height

I pasted SVG code from illustrator and put inside a div.
The div has no height value. the height is set by the SVG

[image: extra pixles and offset at the top]

[image]

The Div show height with +2.67px

The SVG height is 30px like it should be but for some reason, there is an offset at the top  you can see 
the white thin line.

Why does it happen? is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried and test and figure out it has something to do with `display` value.
when I changed the parent DIV to `display:flex` it was all the same height, sometimes the path still goes over the actual  and  tags but I guess it is because of the shape and pixel rendering